# Why warnning doesn't show deprecation message

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import warnings

def deprecate_something(arg1):
    arguments_by_list = do_something(arg1)
    print("Running deprecation check on arg1")
    warnings.warn(
        f"""
        arg1 attribute is deprecated. use {arguments_by_list}
        """,
        DeprecationWarning,
    )
    return arg1

deprecate_something("HelloWorld")
```

running this code gives:

```
Running deprecation check on arg1
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show the deprecation message as well.

Comment: I can't repro; it prints a warning for me with Python 3.8.2 on MacOS.

Comment: How are you running your code? What version of python are using? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Try to set warnings.simplefilter("always").  Just read the warnings module documentation for details.

Comment: @Daweo Running python3.7 on mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code works for me and show the print and the warning. As others pointed out in the comment maybe try the changing the filter on the warnings. I would try out `warnings.simplefilter("always")`, `warnings.simplefilter("default")`, `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")`, to see if something changes at all. You can also check if something along these lines is set in your system

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::DeprecationWarning"
```

What you can also check if you maybe filter out stderr in your terminal, IDE, wherever you run it. The first messages "Running deprecation check on arg1" is written to stdout, the second one, the warning is written to stderr.

If I filter out stderr or stdout I get the following results.

```
python dep_warn_test.py 2> /dev/null
>'Running deprecation check on arg1'


python dep_warn_test.py 1> /dev/null
>'dep_warn_test.py:19: DeprecationWarning: 
         arg1 attribute is deprecated. use do_something
    
   warnings.warn('
```

I tested it on python 3.7.3 on windows and on 3.8.5 on ubuntu.